# How can I print the report without the first in the list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to display the names except the 'name' and trying to get the average of age without 'age' on the list and lastly get the average of the grade without the 'Grade'.

I have a problem I'm trying to print the names of the list without the first row in the `list(['Name', 'Age', 'Grade'])` without pop or removing them from the list.

```
studentDB = [['Name', 'Age', 'Grade'], ['Con', 20, 90.2],
['Juan', 45, 70.2], ['Jed', 39, 100.0]]

while True:
    for i in range(len(studentDB)):
         print(i, studentDB[i])
            
    print("\n**********  Hackathon  ***********")
    CRUD = """1- Add
2- Delete
3- Edit
4- Print Report
----------------
Enter a number: """
    choice = float(input(CRUD))
    if (choice == 1):
        Name = input("Please Enter your Name: ")
        Age = int(input("Please Enter your Age: "))
        Grade = float(input("Please Enter your Grade: "))
        
        studentDB.append([Name, Age, Grade])

        print(studentDB)
    elif (choice == 2):
        Del = int(input("Please Enter the row you want to delete: "))
        studentDB.pop(Del)
    elif (choice == 3):
        Del1 = int(input("Please Enter the row you want to delete: "))
        Name1 = input("Please Enter your Name: ")
        Age1 = int(input("Please Enter your Age: "))
        Grade1 = float(input("Please Enter your Grade: "))
        
        studentDB.pop(Del1)
        studentDB.insert(Del1,[Name1, Age1, Grade1])
        print(studentDB)
    elif (choice == 4):
        #here is the problem
        for s in range(1, len(studentDB)): 
            print("")
        print(f"There are in the {s} student table. The people included in the list are.")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

[Here is the output that I wanted to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRO0H.png)

This is the online compiler: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: Show output as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: I think you need slicing, but I can be wrong.

Comment: I forgot to include my initialization how can I edit it

Comment: There is edit option below the post

Comment: it needs to approve to be edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many ways to solve this. One could be to use starting index in range and use slice while calculating average of age or grades.

````
 from statistics import mean
 while True:
    # Use the start index in range.
    for i in range(len(studentDB)):
         print(i, studentDB[i])
            
    print("\n**********  Hackathon  ***********")
    CRUD = """1- Add
2- Delete
3- Edit
4- Print Report
----------------
Enter a number: """
    choice = float(input(CRUD))
    if (choice == 1):
        Name = input("Please Enter your Name: ")
        Age = int(input("Please Enter your Age: "))
        Grade = float(input("Please Enter your Grade: "))
        
        studentDB.append([Name, Age, Grade])

        print(studentDB)
    elif (choice == 2):
        Del = int(input("Please Enter the row you want to delete: "))
        studentDB.pop(Del)
    elif (choice == 3):
        Del1 = int(input("Please Enter the row you want to delete: "))
        Name1 = input("Please Enter your Name: ")
        Age1 = int(input("Please Enter your Age: "))
        Grade1 = float(input("Please Enter your Grade: "))
        
        studentDB.pop(Del1)
        studentDB.insert(Del1,[Name1, Age1, Grade1])
        print(studentDB)
    elif (choice == 4):
        #here is the problem
        # Use slice to get the row from index 1 afterwards
        print(f"There are in the {len(studentDB) - 1} records in the student table. The people included in the list are.")
        print(",".join([student[0] for student in studentDB[1:]]))
        average_age = mean([row[1] for row in studentDB[1:]])
        average_grades = mean([row[2] for row in studentDB[1:]])
        # Print average age and grades here
    else:
        print("Invalid input")```
````

Comment: but how can i display the names without the 'Name' in the first list?